# i want to get a specific value from this php array

Tags: php, arrays, moodle

I'm new in Moodle Development and currently im creating a new Custom Block that will show the current courses the user is enrolled in. I'm capable of getting the current courses the user is enrolled in using this function :

```
$courses = enrol_get_my_courses();
```

But currently im not capable of extracting the Full name of the Course from the returned array of this function.

The Result of the Array is :

```
array(1) { [3]=> object(stdClass)#581 (11) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["category"]=> string(1) "1" ["sortorder"]=> string(5) "20001" ["shortname"]=> string(3) "CAT" ["fullname"]=> string(4) "Cat2" ["idnumber"]=> string(0) "" ["startdate"]=> string(10) "1460757600" ["visible"]=> string(1) "0" ["groupmode"]=> string(1) "0" ["groupmodeforce"]=> string(1) "0" ["cacherev"]=> string(10) "1460882387" } }
```

So all i want is to get the ["fullname"] value from the previous array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you encapsulated an object into the array, you can access its values like this:

```
$courses[3]->fullname
```

Array values are accessed this way:

```
$array['key']
```

Object values are accessed like this:

```
$object->key
```